# How to upgrade Instagram client from Sandbox to Live production mode?

Tags: permissions, instagram, instagram-api, sandbox, live

I created an app that is running ok in IG Sandbox mode with about invited 5 users, and then I submited a permission request(basic) to go into live mode.

It has been about 1 month now since the my request was made and I still got no response from IG!
My IG developer page keep showing me just a "Pending Review" message.

I searched for a message in my email and see none until now.

Is this normal? 
One month seems to be too much of a time to get just a response...
How long does it usually takes to get at least a response from IG?
Is there anything I can do to solve this or should I just keep waiting?